# How can I delete a record, child records and grandchildren records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have three tables - bands, gigs and assigns (which assigns a gig to the  registered user that entered it to create a many-many relationship between gigs and users.)

The tables are:

```
Bands: bandID, bandname
Gigs: GigID, bandID, venue, date
Assigns: assignID, gigid, userid (which is then linked to the users table)
```

A function on the site is to delete a band, but then it goes "Oh, before you delete the band, it'll delete all these gigs", then the user chooses confirm and so on.

I need a query that deletes the band, then deletes the gigs where gigs.bandID = bands.bandID, and then deletes the assigns where assigns.gigID = gigs.gigID.

I've worked out the SELECT statement and this displays the record I want to delete from the assigns table by feeding it the bandid.

```
SELECT assigns.*
FROM   bands INNER JOIN
   gigs ON bands.bandid = gigs.bandid INNER JOIN
   gigsaccass ON gigs.gigid = gigsaccass.gigid AND bands.bandid = 91
```

But how do I create a DELETE statement from this?

Comment: Are you talking about cascading delete?By default, cascading delete is disabled on dbs, you have to set cascading delete on those foreign keys so that if you delete a parent record, they will be automatically deleted. you don't have to write a separate delete statements for children and grandchildren records.

Comment: A delete statement can only affect one table. In order to delete from all three layers without violating constraints, you'll need to (a) delete from grandchildren using a three-table join (`delete gc from grandchild as gc join child as c join parent as p`), (b) delete from children using a two-table join (`delete c from child as c join parent as p`), then (c) delete from parent.

Comment: I don't mind using three separate delete statements, it's just writing the delete statement with the two inner joins to delete the records from the assigns table that has me stumped. Deleting the record from gigs and bands is simple enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways you could go about it, but this is the route I'd go if you don't want to do the `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint option...

```
Declare @bandID Int
Set     @bandID = 91

--      Delete the associated gigsaccess records
DELETE  ga
FROM    bands As b
INNER   JOIN gigs As g  
        ON  b.bandid = g.bandid 
INNER   JOIN gigsaccass As ga 
        ON  g.gigid = ga.gigid 
WHERE   b.bandid = @bandID

--      Delete the associated gigs records
DELETE  g
FROM    bands As b
INNER   JOIN gigs As g  
        ON  b.bandid = g.bandid 
WHERE   b.bandid = @bandID

--      Delete the band record
DELETE  b
FROM    bands As b
WHERE   b.bandid = @bandID
```

Comment: And if you want it to be an "all or nothing operation", wrap all of the deletes in a transaction.

Comment: Cheers, that's spot on. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that this can be done, one as has been mentioned is a `Cascading Delete`.  The other would be to effectively recreate a cascading deletion by use of several queries.  Personally I prefer the second option, as it allows you a little bit more control over your data.  Utilizing cascading deletions (especially in a production environment) can lead to rather disastrous consequences if you're not extremely careful.  Undoing a single record deletion can be fairly easy (if it's a simple table), undoing a cascading delete that inadvertently hits against 20 different tables is all but impossible without a database backup.

Comment: Never never never forget that: Utilizing cascading deletions can lead to rather disastrous consequences if you're not extremely careful.

Comment: As was mentioned in the comments of the main post, this is disabled by default on most (all?) DBMS's.  There's a very good reason for this...

Answer (score 0):

As jae555 says, I would say that the ON DELETE CASCADE trigger is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Cascading deletes are nice and easy.. you just need to create your foreign keys a certain way.

```
-- foreign key constraint
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Gigs]  WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Gigs_Band] FOREIGN KEY([BandID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Bands] ([BandID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

-- foreign key constraint
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Assigns]  WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Assigns_Gigs] FOREIGN KEY([GigID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Gigs] ([GigID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

make sure you delete the current foreign key first if you have one..

another way is create triggers.. in particular, `Instead of Delete` triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DELETE_Bands]
   ON dbo.[Bands]
   INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 DELETE FROM [Gigs] WHERE BandID IN (SELECT BandID FROM DELETED)
 DELETE FROM [Bands] WHERE BandID IN (SELECT BandID FROM DELETED)
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [DELETE_Gigs]
   ON dbo.[Gigs]
   INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 DELETE FROM [Assigns] WHERE GigID IN (SELECT GigID FROM DELETED)
 DELETE FROM [Gigs] WHERE GigID IN (SELECT GigID FROM DELETED)
END
GO
```